# SQL Oracle Select, Count, and Inner Join

Tags: oracle, join, count

Having issues creating a query that displays the customerID, customerFirName, and customerZip from the customers table, based on when the customer has purchased more than one vehicle within the sales table. Here are the table creations:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(customerID     INT     PRIMARY KEY,
customerFirName     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerLasName     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerMiName      VARCHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
customerStreet      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
customerState       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
customerCity        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
customerZip     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE SALES
(saleID         INT     PRIMARY KEY,
grossSalePrice      DECIMAL(9,2),
vehicleStatus       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleStatus) IN ('available', 'sold', 'pending')),
saleDate        DATE,
saleMileage     INT,
customerID      INT,
salespersonID       INT,
vehicleVIN      VARCHAR(25),
CONSTRAINT SALES_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(customerID);
```

Here is the desired output:

```
customerID        customerFirName    customerZip    Number_of_Sales
1                 Bob                12345          2
2                 Jim                94949          3
3                 Tom                99330          4
```

Here is what I've tried....I'm having issues creating a single SELECT statement that has an inner join to combine the SALES.customerID field on the CUSTOMERS.customerID field. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerFirName, CUSTOMERS.CustomerID, CUSTOMERS.customerZip, COUNT(SALES.customerID)
FROM CUSTOMERS
INNER JOIN SALES ON CUSTOMERS.customerID=SALES.customerID
GROUP BY SALES.customerID
HAVING COUNT(SALES.customerID) > 1;
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT (CUSTOMERS.customerID), customerFullName, customerZip
FROM CUSTOMERS
INNER JOIN SALES ON CUSTOMERS.customerID=SALES.customerID
GROUP BY SALES.customerID
HAVING COUNT(SALES.customerID) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the issus is on `group by` field.

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerFirName, CUSTOMERS.CustomerID, CUSTOMERS.customerZip, 
COUNT(SALES.customerID)
FROM CUSTOMERS
INNER JOIN SALES ON CUSTOMERS.customerID=SALES.customerID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.customerFirName, CUSTOMERS.CustomerID, CUSTOMERS.customerZip
HAVING COUNT(SALES.customerID) > 1;
```

Comment: !!!!! WOW. I am a dummy. Can't believe I missed that - thanks a million, sometimes all you need is someone to point out your overlooked mistakes.

Comment: I am glad.I can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just do a count in a sub select:

```
select * from
(SELECT CUSTOMERS.customerFirName, CUSTOMERS.CustomerID, CUSTOMERS.customerZip, COUNT(*) num_sales
FROM CUSTOMERS
INNER JOIN SALES ON CUSTOMERS.customerID=SALES.customerID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.customerFirName, CUSTOMERS.CustomerID, CUSTOMERS.customerZip)
where num_sales > 1;
```